# Admin Dashboard UI Kits

Tags: sql, database, user-interface, admin

I am interested in taking up a learning path which would include web application development using Dashboard Admin UI Kits such as these [Link to example](https://elements.envato.com/factory-admin-dashboard-ui-kit-TPGY3U5)

1. What application and or languages are used when implementing such a
   UI ?
2. What databases are to be used in the backend?

[image: Example Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the UI:

Languages are always the same: HTML, CSS, JavaScript. Yet, they have countless libraries.
For CSS, I would check Bootstrap (or Bulma if you want slightly less pain), which is a simpler but richer one compared to many others.
For JS, I would check some animation libraries (there are many), and probably not start with any JS framework such as React, Angular etc. They might come later once you feel comfortable with JavaScript.
For HTML, you already have dashboard kit already. Though a great idea for learning, but as far as I know using templates is not a common practice for bigger companies etc.

For the backend:

It really depends on what you want to focus more on. Programming languages have advantages and disadvantages. You can work with (almost) any language but increasingly more popular ones are Node.js, Django (Python's popular web framework) etc. For beginning, these two are nice options. Node.js is also closely related to JavaScript, so that is a big plus.

For the database:

You might want to check if you need relational data or not, because that might narrow down your options. MongoDB is easy to learn and to get the basics of backend programming, while SQL (PostgreSQL is a nice example) is a widely preferred SQL option one in the industry.